# Why does my activity reset when I tap on the back button?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a back button in one activity and when I tap on it to return to the parent activity it will reset the parent activity. It's like `onCreate()` is being called again. I'm not sure why that is because when you tap on the back button it just calls `finish()` to exist the activity I'm currently in.

Here is how I'm declaring the toolbar:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
   {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
   }
```

This is what happens when you tap on the button:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The strange this is that when I hit the save button I return to the parent activity without any reset. So I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: did you check the heap when you return to the parent activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return true or else it will always call the `onCreat()` method. Also, you can create an "empty" intent and just not process it on the activity you return true.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(Intent_Constant.TAPPED_BACK_BUTTON, intent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```